# Assign validation group to "All" validation constraint - Symfony 2.5

Tags: validation, symfony

I have phone field in my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 * @Assert\All({
 *     @Assert\NotBlank(),
 *     @Assert\Length(
 *          min = 5,
 *          minMessage = "Your phone number must be at least {{ limit }} characters long"
 * )
 * })
 */
protected $phone;
```

These validations works as "default" validation groups without any problems, but when I add a validation group like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 * @Assert\All({
 *     @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"profile"}]),
 *     @Assert\Length(
 *          min = 5,
 *          minMessage = "Your phone number must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
 *          groups={"profile"}
 * )
 * })
 */
protected $phone;
```

It doesn't work! Maybe there is mistake in syntax or something...
What I have missed?

Comment: "It doesn't work!"? Seriously? Come on, you have to give us something more than that...

Comment: It just doesn't validate phone input, I can save form with empty input. I have name field in "profile" validations group which validates length and is working perfect, but I really don't know why phone field doesn't validates. I have never seen any example where are "all" validation constraint with validation group assigned, that's why I am asking experts for help.

Answer (score 2):

Looking over the official documentation I can see that there is little infomation about this one.

Have you tried something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 * @Assert\All({
 *     @Assert\NotBlank(),
 *     @Assert\Length(min = 5, minMessage = "Your phone number must be at least {{ limit }} characters long")
  * }, groups={"profile"})
  */
 protected $phone;
```

Comment: Yes, in official documentation is little information. Thank you for try, unfortunately this example throws an error.

Comment: Can you please include the error message? I don't have access to my dev box so I'm doing blind here :)

Comment: Syntax error: `AnnotationException: [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ',' at position 200 in property RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\User::$phone.`

Comment: Very interesting is that in my second example Symfony doesn't throw any error, just don't work.

Answer (score 1):

This way works fine for me on Symfony 2.3 (2.3.25):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 * @Assert\All(
 *     constraints={
 *         @Assert\NotBlank(),
 *         @Assert\Length(min = 5, minMessage = "Your phone number must be at least {{ limit }} characters long")
 *     }, 
 *     groups={"profile"}
 * )
 */
 protected $phone;
```

Answer (score -1):

You were almost there. You have to give a key to the array that you are passing to your Validator or else you won't be able to have an array with multiple items. All you need add the key constraints and then you'll be able to add your groups. It is important that you add the groups to all your Validators.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 * @Assert\All(constraints = {
 *     @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"profile"}]),
 *     @Assert\Length(
 *          min = 5,
 *          minMessage = "Your phone number must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
 *          groups={"profile"}
 *     )
 * }, groups={"profile"})
 */
protected $phone;
```